# Is there a word for "guessing in favor of someone"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for the situation when you don't know the truth but you decided to guess the best for one person. Such as in "I don't know if she has washed her hands or not, but let's just believe she did."

Answer (score 3):

You give someone the [*benefit of the doubt*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/benefit+of+the+doubt).

> a judgment in one's favor when the evidence is neither for one nor against one.

<sub>(source: The Free Dictionary)</sub>

Comment: Thank you ever soooo much!!!!! I was so sad, trying to remember that phrase for almost an hour!